# TableViewController - Half a view / half a tableView scrolling is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

I've a TableViewController with the top half as a RegularView, and the other half is my table. But I've a problem the whole thing is not scrollable, I can go down a bit, but as soon as I let i go It goes back to the top :/

AnyIdeas?

P.S. Scrolling Enabled is ticked for the Tableview

EDIT : PrintScreen of what I'm doing : http://postimage.org/image/lldwd0ybl/

Comment: didnt get u .... the uiview is on top of the uitableview?

Comment: Yep, that's right I've a UIView on top of my UITableView. Sorry if I'm not clear, sometimes is hard to explain thing :D

Comment: But please tell me wat u want to achieve frm this ? Its not clear wat is ur problem ?

Comment: I update my post with a printscreen I hope it's more clear now?

Comment: What I want to do is have the whole View scrollable at the moment if I've more than 2 cells I can't see them :/ Cause the view is not scrollable and so I can't reach them :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `UITableViewController` the `view` property of this controller is by default the table view. Thus, you have limited options of adding other views to the view hierarchy.

You should perhaps use an ordinary `UIViewController` which is the superclass of the table view controller. You can easily add a top view *and* a table view as subview to the main `view` of this controller. To make the table view work, you need to also follow these steps:

1. Add the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to your class, and set your table view's `datasource` and `delegate` accordingly (or hook them up in IB).
2. Implement the the datasource and delegate methods (they won't be automatically provided to you as when you use the UITableViewController template).

Note that you cannot use storyboard's static tables with this setup.

Comment: I'll try this I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

The thing is not clear here about your implementation but what you can do this are:(since you want full scrolling means your rectangle as well as table view)

1) Just increase the row height at index 0 or where-ever you want to show the box and can also customize according to your need, it'll properly scroll as you want, &;

2) You put your custom view(it's may be UIView, UIImageView, or whatever) and table-view within a scroll-view and work-out accordingly.

I suggest you go with the first approach as according to me it's little bit easy approach.

In any concern, let me know. :)